# Why Nexus is not downloading an artifact which is listed in the index?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, nexus, sonatype

Using Maven I'm trying to add a new dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>seam-bom</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>   
</dependency>
```

Browsing Nexus repository index corresponding to the JBoss repository, I can see the artifact:

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

But if I browse the repository storage in Nexus, the artifact is no present, and I when I try to build the project, I get an error:

```
Failure to find org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:pom:3.1.0.Final in http://eplus.cci.gc.es/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Comment: Try to run the mvn command with **-U** option

Comment: @Skizzo I already tried it, now I'm executing that command to build:
`mvn clean compile package -U`

Comment: @Skizzo `-U` is only for SNAPSHOTs and **not** for releases.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow -U didn't work for you - you could remove it manually from your local maven repository or use this command **mvn dependency:purge-local-repository** (it will clean all project dependencies from local repo)

For more info take a look here - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html

Comment: I removed all my local repository to force maven to get the artifacts from Nexus, and I got the same error: **Could not find artifact org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:pom:3.1.0.Final in nexus (http://eplus.cci.gc.es/nexus/content/groups/public)**
@Mysterion

Comment: pom.xml http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2gsgnF62
I don't see relevant information in settings.xml, but I can upload it too if it's useful. @Mysterion

Answer (score 0):

The Seam Maven dependencies are not hosted by Maven Central.

Add this in your pom.xml.

```
<project...
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: Yes @Iker-Aguayo there are not hosted by Maven Central, but we've added the JBoss repository in our Nexus (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/), as a proxy repository, to get those artifacts. And in that repository, you can find the artifact: https://repository.jboss.org/org/jboss/seam/seam-bom/3.1.0.Final/seam-bom-3.1.0.Final.pom

Comment: Can you post your setting.xml?

Comment: Could you try to add the repository configuration in your settings.xml First the central and then the one I gave you.

Comment: Done, this the settings profiles part:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4mdD71Dd

With the same result: `Failure to find org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:pom:3.1.0.Final in http://eplus.cci.gc.es/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Comment: So, if you do not want to add the above snippet in your pom.xml, despite that you added the jBoss repo in your Nexus, I can not help you. Sorry.

Comment: I'm following all your instructions @Iker-Aguayo and I appreciate your help, thanks. I added the snippet in the pom, but I still get the same error.
pom.xml --> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ms33V8Pu